# Android permanent storage

Tags: android, storage

I want to create a file and I don't want it to be deleted when the application data is cleared. Is there a way for this in android, something like permanent storage ?

Comment: I'm not asking file format :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can save to external storage (typically the SD card). See the section in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) entitled **Saving files that should be shared**:

> If you want to save files that are not specific to your application
>   and that should not be deleted when your application is uninstalled,
>   save them to one of the public directories on the external storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite for permanent storage. It will do the job perfectly. Avoid using `GetExternalFilesDir()` if you do not want the data to be deleted when the application removed.

This tutorial from Google will tell you about all options for storage
[Data Storage in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)